# Issues using MongoDB with meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm making a booking website with meteor. I'm so trying to use a database to store the reservations and to display them in a table. The problem is that I don't manage to use MongoDB. Here is the code :

```
function readBooking() {
      var Reservations_db = new Mongo.Collection('reservations');
      var name = document.getElementById("nom").value;
      var formula = document.getElementById("formule").value;
      var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
      var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
      Reservations_db.insert({ name: name, formula: formula, time: time, length: length });
    }
    function verifypsw() {
      var Reservations_db = new Mongo.Collection('reservations');
      if (document.getElementById("psw").value == "massage") {
        localStorage.setItem('admin', true);
        document.getElementById('verifyid').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('reservationstable').style.display = "block";
        console.log(Reservations_db.find({ name: "Noé" }).fetch());
      }
    }
```

When I book, this error comes up in the console: `Uncaught Error: There is already a collection named "reservations"`

I tried removing the `new` in this line `var Reservations_db = new Mongo.Collection('reservations');` like this :

```
function readBooking() {
      var Reservations_db = Mongo.Collection('reservations');
      var name = document.getElementById("nom").value;
      var formula = document.getElementById("formule").value;
      var time = document.getElementById("time").value;
      var length = document.getElementById("length").value;
      Reservations_db.insert({ name: name, formula: formula, time: time, length: length });
    }
    function verifypsw() {
      var Reservations_db = Mongo.Collection('reservations');
      if (document.getElementById("psw").value == "massage") {
        localStorage.setItem('admin', true);
        document.getElementById('verifyid').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('reservationstable').style.display = "block";
        console.log(Reservations_db.find({ name: "Noé" }).fetch());
      }
    }
```

But then this error comes up: `Uncaught TypeError: this._maybeSetUpReplication is not a function`

What should I do?

Comment: Define the collection outside the functions.

Comment: It still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

All collections should be defined only once ever, not in multiple functions. Declare the collection in its own file and import that file to insert, find, etc. This will also make it easier for you in the long-term as you can create your data model in that separate file.